# Getting Exception while loading initramfs in linux

Tags: linux, initramfs, u-boot

I am getting exception while booting the linux initramfs from uboot.

my bootargs are:
setenv bootargs 'console=ttySC0,115200 root=/dev/ram rw ramdisk_size=51200'
booti 0x60E00000 0x70000000 0x62000000

Call trace points in ***free_initrd_mem***.
Giving exception while freeing the initramfs file system.

Anyone suggest, what is the root cause? Do i need to change the bootargs?

Thanks.

Boot Log:

[    0.175106] Unpacking initramfs...

[    0.653408] BUG: Bad page state in process swapper/0  pfn:70400

[    0.653424] page:ffffffbdc1c10000 count:0 mapcount:-127 mapping:          (null) index:0x0

[    0.653428] flags: 0x0()

[    0.653433] page dumped because: nonzero mapcount

[    0.653437] Modules linked in:

[    0.653447] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.0-yocto-standard #16

[    0.653451] Hardware name: Visteon Monarch board based on Renesas r8a7795 (DT)

[    0.653456] Call trace:

[    0.653473] [] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x180

[    0.653479] [] show_stack+0x14/0x20

[    0.653488] [] dump_stack+0x90/0xc8

[    0.653497] [] bad_page+0xc8/0x118

[    0.653502] [] free_pages_prepare+0x1dc/0x248

[    0.653506] [] free_hot_cold_page+0x28/0x1b8

[    0.653510] [] __free_pages+0x40/0x50

[    0.653514] [] free_reserved_area+0x8c/0x110

[    0.653524] [] free_initrd_mem+0x20/0x2c

[    0.653529] [] populate_rootfs+0x9c/0xbc

[    0.653534] [] do_one_initcall+0x8c/0x190

[    0.653539] [] kernel_init_freeable+0x148/0x1ec

[    0.653549] [] kernel_init+0x10/0xe0

[    0.653554] [] ret_from_fork+0x10/0x40

[    0.653557] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint

Comment: Is `booti` a typo ?

Comment: No, 'booti' is a command used to boot arm64 Linux Image image from memory.

Comment: kernel version and, if possible, list of loaded modules, please.

Comment: linux version 4.4. I am able to get initramfs Shell with this exception.

Comment: Please give the whole log, from power-on to oops.

Comment: complete log attached in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07LU9KVF96fZGpVZHI1aGNpU00/view

Comment: @TomRini  Any idea on this issue?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar I meant the whole console log from power on to hang.  If there's something "sensitive" in there, just edit those line(s), carefully.

Answer (score 0):

My `initrd` image size is very less compared with RAM. So I retained the `initrd` image without freeing in kernel using below `bootargs`.

```
set bootargs 'retain_initrd'
```